# Oracle Audit on Types

Tags: oracle, audit

I found that auditing can be done on oracle schema objects like procedures and views. Is there any possibility to do the auditing on **Types**?

Comment: Is there any possibility to do the auditing on Types? what do you mean? what are the Types you want, can you name few??

Comment: I mean data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types can be altered, granted/revoked privileges on, so why not?

Example:

```
SQL> select object_type from dba_objects where object_name = 'T1';

no rows selected

SQL> create type t1 is table of varchar2(20);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> audit all on t1;

Audit succeeded.

SQL> select * from dba_obj_audit_opts where object_name = 'T1';

OWNER                OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE             ALT       AUD       COM       DEL       GRA       IND       INS       LOC       REN       SEL       UPD       REF EXE       CRE       REA       WRI       FBK
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
BP                   T1                   TYPE                    A/A       A/A       -/-       -/-       A/A       -/-       -/-       -/-       -/-       -/-       -/-       -/- A/A       A/A       -/-       -/-       -/-
```

See [DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS.html#GUID-A6E91022-1EF6-4805-A567-6E5AC45F8FC9) and [AUDIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/AUDIT-Traditional-Auditing.html#GUID-ADF45B07-547A-4096-8144-50241FA2D8DD) for details.